# Array.join() method's separator is ignored

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```js
const inpobjarray = [
  {
    'books': 50
  },
  {
    'grocery': 10
  }
]

inpobjarray.forEach(i => {
  console.log({
    ...i,
    'StringToPrint': Object.entries(i).join(':')
  })
})
```

I expected the `StringToPrint` to be joined by the separator `'-'` but instead my output still contains the default `,` separator as shown in the image below

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYdE7.png)

Can someone tell me what mistake I have made ?

Comment: You're stringifying each _entry_ array (`[key, value]`) which by default formats as a comma-separated list. What should the result be if there is more than one property in each object?

Comment: I've added an example into my answer below but you'll need to clarify

Comment: Thanks Phil. I understood the mistake I was making earlier. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stringifying each *entry* array (`[key, value]`) which by default formats as a comma-separated list.

I would suggest mapping each entry to the string format you want.

```js
const inpobjarray = [
  {
    'books': 50,
  },
  {
    'grocery': 10,
    'another': 'property',
  }
]

inpobjarray.forEach((i) => {
  console.log({
    ...i,
    StringToPrint: Object.entries(i)
      .map((pair) => pair.join("-")) // join each each key / value pair
      .join(","), // join the resulting array
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```